# Excel Summation Formula Update

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge file that's connected to an Access Database.
One worksheet is the calculation worksheet and the other worksheet is the summary worksheet that summarizes the calculations.

On the summary worksheet I have a column called Actuals, and another called Estimated.

ID | Actuals | Estimate

A  | ####### | #######
B  | ####### | #######
.
.
.

The actual column sums up columns from the calculated column from A to Z referencing the ID.

The estimate column sums up columns from the calculated column from AA to AZ referencing the ID.

Every month I would like the sums to move over by one. For example,
if this month the actuals summed from A to Z, and the estimates summed from AA to AZ, the next month I would like the formula to update to: actuals = sum from A to AA and estimate = sum from AB to BA.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show what formula you have now ?  without seeing more, I'd be tempted to suggest OFFSET ... might work well .. not sure without seeing your actual formula, though

Comment: I think you want the second set in AB to BB. The A-Z grew a column to A-AA as well as offset one column.

Comment: @Ditto , I just have a regular sum formula: sum(A:Z) and sum(AA:AZ)